# Selenium .net Binary location failed VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, selenium, browser, automation

it is very strange when i used this code **everything is fine**.

```
Public driver As IWebDriver
driver = New ChromeDriver("C:\")
```

**But when i tried using chromeoptions** object code written below. Seems **never success** at all!

```
Dim service As ChromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService()
        service.HideCommandPromptWindow = True

        Dim chromeOptions As New ChromeOptions()
        chromeOptions.BinaryLocation = "C:\"
        chromeOptions.AddArgument("start-minimized")


        driver = New ChromeDriver(service, chromeOptions)
```

The error message is:

> 'OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException' occurred in
>   WebDriver.dll

What the configurations i forgot?

Comment: Is the driver located in your C:\?

Comment: ya thats true.
the chromedriver.exe is located in C: just like my 1st code working.
But why the 2nd code unable to accomplish the samething?

Answer (score 0):

ChromeOptions.BinaryLocation is for specifying the location of Chrome.exe, not for specifying ChromeDriver.exe

Comment: how about if i want to use chromedriver.exe using ChromeOptions code ?

Comment: Pass it in ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(pathToChromeDriver);

Comment: no luck @Arnon, i still got error code : OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException